How can I apply custom styles to the select dropdown without affecting other MUI components, like the show/hide columns panel?
I'm trying to add custom styles to the dropdown panel of my MUI select component. I want the dropdown to look like this:
Desired show/hide columns example
To do this, I added the following styles to the MuiList in my ThemeManager:
    MuiList: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          'backgroundColor': 'var(--main-color)',
          'color': 'var(--text-color-light)',
          'border-width': 'none !important',

          '& .Mui-selected': {
            backgroundColor: '#dddddd !important',
            'color': 'var(--primary-color-hover) !important',
            borderBottom: '1px solid #26586B',
            '&:hover': {
              backgroundColor: 'var(--main-color) !important',
              color: 'var(--primary-color-hover) !important',
            },
          },
...

However, this change is also affecting other MUI components, like the "Show/Hide Columns" panel in a data table, which looks like this:
Custom dropdown style
The issue is that I can’t add a unique id or className to the dropdown panel, as it’s dynamically generated by MUI. This results in the ThemeManager styles being applied to both the select dropdown and other components, like the columns panel, which I don’t want.
In the end, this is how the columns panel looks with the ThemeManager styles applied, which is not what I want:
Incorrectly styled show/hide all panel
Is there a way to target only the select dropdown for styling without affecting other MUI components like the show/hide columns panel?

You should not overwrite css in MUI's theme file, the problem you encounter is because many MUI components use the MuiList component (There are many basic components that are reused in complex components such as Drawer, Table, ...).
You also cannot css through class from sx or makeStyles because the dropdown of select is not a child component inside the root select but it creates a node outside the body tag (equal to the root if using react).
There are 2 ways to handle droppdown styles:

styled() utility: this way helps us create a completely new component based on an existing MUI component and write the css type. The advantage is that we can reuse this new component in different screens.
Through MenuProps: usually for components that are displayed outside the body (portal style), MUi components often provide props to handle that, for example in the select component, it is the MenuProps props


Thanks, I actually managed to add a custom class through the MenuProps like this:
 MenuProps={{
                    PaperProps: {
                      className: 'custom-dropdown',
                    },
                  }}

By doing this, I achieved the styling I wanted.
